# Unexpected Error in haskell that i cant understand

Tags: haskell

I have an in input like this : statistics [(0,1),(1,3),(1,2)] where i want to  calculate some infos. Ok with that but when am using  recursion in order to create a loop it sends me an error that i dont know why . All i want is at (head s) to take (x,y) values and in (tail s) to keep the other list as it is .
My code :

```
statistics :: [(Int,Int)]->(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
statistics [] = (0,0,0,0,0)
statistics s = help_statistics s (head s) (tail s) 0 0 0 0 0 0
                                                            
help_statistics :: [(Int,Int)]->(Int,Int)->[(Int,Int)]->Int->Int->Int->Int->Int->Int->(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
help_statistics s (x,y) taill counter matches total_points goal_for goal_against dif
                                                                            |counter==0 =  help_statistics s (head taill) (tail taill) (counter+1) length(s) total_points goal_for goal_against dif
                                                                            |otherwise  = (matches,total_points,goal_for,goal_against,dif)

 ERROR file:.\LAB3.hs:11 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : help_statistics s (head taill) (tail taill) (counter + 1) length s total_points goal_for goal_against dif
*** Term           : help_statistics
*** Type           : [(Int,Int)] -> (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> (Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f -> g -> h -> i -> j -> k
```

Comment: `(length s)` instead of `length(s)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are amazing :P  thank you !

Comment: You probably want to put most of those arguments in a record, so it's easier to read. Also, [the "go" pattern](https://kowainik.github.io/posts/haskell-mini-patterns#recursive-go) is a nice trick, so you don't have to repeat all the arguments that don't change in a recursive call

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can i ask somthing else ? if i set as input this [(1,5),(3,5)] , i had a pattern match failure : head []  how i can solve this ?

Comment: Ah, yes. You should try to avoid using the functions `head` and `tail` as much as possible. Instead use pattern matching, like `f (x:xs) = something; f [] = something else` or `f xs = case xs of (x:xs) -> something; [] -> something else` (replace semicolon with newline if you want)

Answer (score 0):

Let me go through the code and help you with issues and make it more idiomatic.

Let's start by fixing the `length(s)` -> `(length s)` issue and reducing the indentation so it fits better on the screen.

```
statistics :: [(Int,Int)]->(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
statistics [] = (0,0,0,0,0)
statistics s = help_statistics s (head s) (tail s) 0 0 0 0 0 0

help_statistics :: [(Int,Int)]->(Int,Int)->[(Int,Int)]->Int->Int->Int->Int->Int->Int->(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
help_statistics s (x,y) taill counter matches total_points goal_for goal_against dif
    |counter==0 =  help_statistics s (head taill) (tail taill) (counter+1) (length s) total_points goal_for goal_against dif
    |otherwise  = (matches,total_points,goal_for,goal_against,dif)
```

Next we can replace `head` and `tail` with pattern matching:

```
statistics :: [(Int,Int)]->(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
statistics [] = (0,0,0,0,0)
statistics s@(x:xs) = help_statistics s x xs 0 0 0 0 0 0

help_statistics :: [(Int,Int)]->(Int,Int)->[(Int,Int)]->Int->Int->Int->Int->Int->Int->(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
help_statistics s (x,y) (hd:tl) counter matches total_points goal_for goal_against dif
    |counter==0 =  help_statistics s hd tl (counter+1) (length s) total_points goal_for goal_against dif
    |otherwise  = (matches,total_points,goal_for,goal_against,dif)
help_statistics s (x,y) [] counter matches total_points goal_for goal_against dif
   = _ -- What should we do with an empty list?
```

Next step is to introduce a new data type, so we don't have to work with a gazillion arguments and count which argument we want each time:

```
data Statistics = MkStatistics
  { matches      :: Int
  , total_points :: Int
  , goal_for     :: Int
  , goal_against :: Int
  , dif          :: Int
  } deriving Show

emptyStatistics :: Statistics
emptyStatistics = MkStatistics 0 0 0 0 0

statistics :: [(Int,Int)] -> Statistics
statistics [] = emptyStatistics
statistics s@(x:xs) = help_statistics s x xs 0 emptyStatistics

help_statistics :: [(Int,Int)]->(Int,Int)->[(Int,Int)]->Int-> Statistics -> Statistics
help_statistics s (x,y) (hd:tl) counter stats
    |counter==0 = let stats' = stats {matches = length s} -- Update `matches` to a new value
                  in help_statistics s hd tl (counter+1) stats'
    |otherwise  = stats
help_statistics s (x,y) [] counter stats
   = _ -- What should we do with an empty list?
```

Next we can use pattern matching for `counter==0` as well

```
data Statistics = MkStatistics
  { matches      :: Int
  , total_points :: Int
  , goal_for     :: Int
  , goal_against :: Int
  , dif          :: Int
  } deriving Show

emptyStatistics :: Statistics
emptyStatistics = MkStatistics 0 0 0 0 0

statistics :: [(Int,Int)] -> Statistics
statistics [] = emptyStatistics
statistics s@(x:xs) = help_statistics s x xs 0 emptyStatistics

help_statistics :: [(Int,Int)]->(Int,Int)->[(Int,Int)]->Int-> Statistics -> Statistics
help_statistics s (x,y) (hd:tl) counter@0 stats
    -- When counter == 0, increase it by 1 (i.e. set it to 1)
    -- Is this really what was intended?
    = help_statistics s hd tl (counter+1) stats'
  where stats' = stats {matches = length s} -- Update `matches` to a new value
help_statistics s (x,y) (hd:tl) counter stats
   = stats -- when counter is not 0, return the stats. Was this reversed?
help_statistics s (x,y) [] counter stats
   = _ -- What should we do with an empty list?
```

We can also use pattern matching to avoid having two separate arguments for the head and the tail, but now we've slightly changed the behaviour

```
data Statistics = MkStatistics
  { matches      :: Int
  , total_points :: Int
  , goal_for     :: Int
  , goal_against :: Int
  , dif          :: Int
  } deriving Show

emptyStatistics :: Statistics
emptyStatistics = MkStatistics 0 0 0 0 0

statistics :: [(Int,Int)] -> Statistics
statistics s = help_statistics s s 0 emptyStatistics

help_statistics :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)] -> Int -> Statistics -> Statistics
help_statistics s ((x,y):tl) counter@0 stats
    -- When counter == 0, increase it by 1 (i.e. set it to 1)
    -- Is this really what was intended?
    = help_statistics s tl (counter+1) stats'
  where stats' = stats {matches = length s} -- Update `matches` to a new value
help_statistics s (_:_) counter stats
   = stats -- when counter is not 0, return the stats. Was this reversed?
help_statistics s [] counter stats
   = stats -- What should we do with an empty list?
```